# C++ - Quitting a program

Tags: c++, cin

In the **C++ Without Fear: A Beginner's Guide That Makes You Feel Smart** book in chapter(8), part of a code trying to display a text file is the following:

```
while(1)
{
    for(int i=1; i <= 24 && !file_in.eof(); i++)
    {
        file_in.getline(input_line,80);
        std::cout<<input_line<<std::endl;
    }

    if(file_in.eof())
    {
        break;
    }

    std::cout<<"More? (Press 'Q' and ENTER to quit.)";
    std::cin.getline(input_line,80);
    c=input_line[0]; // <<<<<<
    if(c=='Q'||c=='q')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The part I'm not getting here is:

```
c=input_line[0];
```

I think it is put to read 'Q' or 'q'. But, why using this form (Array)? And, isn't there a way to read 'Q' or 'q' directly?

I tried `std::cin>>c;` but seemed to be incorrect.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your modified code with `std::cin >> c` look like?

Comment: How smart do you feel now? (sorry, I couldn't resist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `input_line` is string ( array from `char`s), so `input_line[0]` gets the first letter - this is in case, that the user write "quit" or "Quit", not just "Q"

`std::cin >> c;` would be correct, if you enter just one `char` and press `Enter`

Comment: Why is the program working while "c" is of type "int"? Doesn't the statement "input_line[0]" return a "char"?!

Comment: @SWEngineer:  Default promotion.  You can always take an integral value (and `char` counts) and assign it to a variable of a larger integral type.  It would be better in general to make `c` a `char` instead.

Comment: @SWEngineer - `char` can be treated as `int`. So, comparing an int value (`c`) with `'Q'` or `'q'`, you actually compare the value of `c` with the ACSII code of `'q'` or `'Q'`. Also, `c=input_line[0];` just assigned the first element's ASCII on `c`. As David said, you should declare `c` as `char`, because `int` is larger type (4B, for example, while char is always 1B)

Answer (score 3):

> I tried `std::cin>>c;` but seemed to be incorrect.

That's correct, if `c` is a `char`.

You're right; reading an entire line just to extract a single character is bizarre. I recommend a book from [this list](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Comment: Actually, the book is giving "c" the type "int"!

Comment: @SWEngineer "I recommend a book from this list."

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the first character from the "array" into which the input line has been written.

Answer (score -4):

**NON-STANDARD** solution, but works on windows platforms.

you can use getch() function defined in conio.h
example:

```
#include <conio.h>
...
char c = getch();
```

bye

Comment: Downvoted because conio.h is a non-standard C header and this is a question about standard C++

Comment: I think you missed the point. It's less about this header being non-standard than it is about it being  C header, and the question being about C++. They're not the same language.