# Correct way to cast address of int to char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

If I need to read int from ifstream

```
int myInt = 0;
fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myInt), sizeof(int));
```

is using `reinterpret_cast<char*>` correct way to accomplish that?

Comment: This might be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748232/reinterpret-cast :)

Comment: Consider using `sizeof myInt` to not repeat the type, and to be safe if you later to decide to change the type to e.g. `long` which might be a different size.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a good idea to use `sizeof myInt`

Comment: I am a bit confused on what the actual question is. Is it how to read `int`s from `ifstream` as the question itself seems to indicate or is it how to cast from `int` to `char*` as the title suggests?

Comment: @hmjd: both. It is necessary to cast `int*` to `char*` in order to read an object representation of an `int` from an `ifstream` directly into an `int`. You could avoid reading directly, and thus avoid the cast, by doing something like `char tmp[sizeof myInt]; filestream.read(tmp, sizeof myInt); std::memcpy(&myInt, &tmp, sizeof myInt);`. But it's fairly pointless to write that code solely in order to make this question into two questions ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> is using reinterpret_cast correct way to accomplish that?

Yes. Prefer c++ style casts, instead of c style casts.

As suggested in comments, a better way to use the [read method function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) is :

```
int myInt = 0;
fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myInt), sizeof(myInt));
```

Comment: I disagree with the answer (not the comment about c++ and c style casts), see Jon's answer below.

Comment: @Walter There is a down vote on the left. However, Jon's answer is not going to work if it is being read from a binary file.